# Android - How to determine of time object is between two other time objects?

Tags: android, time

How can I determine if the current time is between two other time objects?

For example: current: 15:23, startTime: 22:00, endTime: 06:00. So the current time is not between this two other times, but this "23:47" is.

*I don't care about the date only the time

I tried to do it like this:

```
Time startTime = getStartTime();
Time endTime = getEndTime();

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Time now = new Time(c.getTimeInMillis());

if (now.before(endTime) && now.after(startTime)) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

but it dosen't work well. their aren't any error but it just dosen't work.

To be more precise the problem is that 15:35.after(22:00) return true... and I don't know why.
I think that the problem is something with the dates but I don't know what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
    Time startTime = getStartTime();
    Time endTime = getEndTime();

    Calendar startCalendarTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCalendarTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, startTime.getHours(), startTime.getMinutes(), 0);

    Calendar endCalendarTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCalendarTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, endTime.getHours(), endTime.getMinutes(), 0);

    Calendar midnightTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    midnightTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 23, 59, 0);

    Calendar nowCalendarTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    nowCalendarTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    if (startCalendarTime.after(endCalendarTime)) {

        if (nowCalendarTime.after(midnightTime)) {
            startCalendarTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        } else {
            endCalendarTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }

    }
    int hours = nowCalendarTime.getTime().getHours();
    int minutes = nowCalendarTime.getTime().getMinutes();
    nowCalendarTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, hours, minutes, 0);

    if (nowCalendarTime.after(startCalendarTime) && nowCalendarTime.before(endCalendarTime)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
long startTime = getStartTime(); // return the as long
long endTime = getEndTime();// return the value as long

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
long now = c.getTimeInMillis();

if (now>startTime && now<endTime) {

    return true;

}

return false;
```

Comment: Because now=23 not (23>21 && 23<00)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just got a typo. You want to use (now.before(endTime) && now.after(startTime)).

Like this:

```
Time startTime = getStartTime();
Time endTime = getEndTime();

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Time now = new Time(c.getTimeInMillis());

if (now.before(endTime) && now.after(startTime)) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: Its not a typo mistake ths mistake was only here and I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I needed 'quiet times' when my app wouldn't announce spoken content.

Here's my solution formatted for ease of reading:

```
private boolean quietTimesOk(final Context ctx) {

    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    final int combined = (hour * 60) + minute;

    final int qtsHour = getQuietTimeStartHour(ctx);
    final int qtsMinute = getQuietTimeStartMinute(ctx);
    final int qtsCombined = (qtsHour * 60) + qtsMinute;

    final int qteHour = getQuietTimeEndHour(ctx);
    final int qteMinute = getQuietTimeEndMinute(ctx);
    final int qteCombined = (qteHour * 60) + qteMinute;

    if (qtsCombined > qteCombined) {            
        Log.i("quietTimesOk", "- qtsCombined > qteCombined");

        if (combined < qtsCombined && combined > qteCombined) {
            Log.i("quietTimesOk", "- returning true");
            return true;
        }

    } else {            
        Log.i("quietTimesOk", "- qtsCombined < qteCombined");

        if (combined < qtsCombined || combined > qteCombined) {
            Log.i("quietTimesOk", "- returning true");
            return true;
        }
    }

    Log.i("quietTimesOk", "- returning false");

    return false;
}
```